# Manipulating drag and drop images in windows forms c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, picturebox

I am trying to write a program which will allow a user to drag and drop images into the program and then be able to select the image, move it about, re-size it, crop it etc.

So far I have created a windows form which consists of a panel. A user can drag a picture file onto the panel and a picturebox will be created at the coordinates of the mouse when it is dropped and an image is loaded in the picturebox. I can add several images in this fashion.

Now I want to allow the user to manipulate and move about the images that they have dropped into the panel.

I have tried searching for solutions but cant seem to find an answer which I understand.

Any help is much appreciated..

This is my current code

```
 private void panel1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.All;
    }



    private void panel1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        String[] imagePaths = (String[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
        foreach (string path in imagePaths)
        {
            Point point = panel1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

            PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.ImageLocation = path;
            pb.Left = point.X;
            pb.Top = point.Y;

            panel1.Controls.Add(pb);

            //g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile(path), point);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the mouse position when the user initially clicks and then track the mouse position in the PictureBox's `MouseMove` event. You can attach these handlers to multiple PictureBoxes.

```
private int xPos;
private int yPos;

private void pb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
       xPos = e.X;
       yPos = e.Y;
    }
}

private void pb_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox p = sender as PictureBox;

    if(p != null)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            p.Top += (e.Y - yPos);
            p.Left +=  (e.X - xPos);
        }
    }
}
```

For dynamic PictureBoxes you can attach the handlers like this

```
PictureBox dpb = new PictureBox();
dpb.MouseDown += pb_MouseDown;
dbp.MouseMove += pb_MouseMove;
//fill the rest of the properties...
```

Comment: If the picturebox is being generated whilst the program is running how do i attach these handlers to the pictureboxes?